# PHP 7.4.8 5.6x faster than same c++ program in similar test (g++ 4.8.5)

Tags: php, c++, performance

I'm absolutely dumbfounded by this.
I was trying to demonstrate to myself how much faster c++ is than even modern PHP.
I ran a simple csv parsing program in both that have the same output.
The csv file is 40,194,684 parsed down to 1,537,194 lines.

PHP Code (runtime 42.750s):

```
<?php
$i_fp = fopen("inFile.csv","r");
$o_fp = fopen("outFile.csv","w");

while(!feof($i_fp))
{
    $line = fgets($i_fp);
    $split = explode(';',$line);
    if($split[3] == 'E' || $split[3] == 'T')
    {
        fwrite($o_fp,join(',',[ $split[0], $split[1], $split[3], $split[4], $split[5], $split[6],
                                $split[10], $split[9],$split[11],$split[7],$split[32]])."\n");
    }
}
fclose($i_fp);
fclose($o_fp);
```

C++ Code (runtime 3m59.074s)
(compiled using `g++ parse.cpp -o parse -O2 -std=c++1y`)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

vector<string> splitStr(string line, const char delimiter = ',')
{
    vector<string> splitLine;
    string buf;
    for(size_t i=0; i<line.length(); i++)
    {
        if(line[i] == delimiter)
        {
            splitLine.push_back(buf);
            buf.clear();
        }else{
            buf += line[i];
        }
    }
    return splitLine;
}
string makeCSVLine(vector<string> splitLine)
{
    string line = 
        splitLine[0] + ',' +
        splitLine[1] + ',' +
        splitLine[3] + ',' +
        splitLine[4] + ',' +
        splitLine[5] + ',' +
        splitLine[6] + ',' +
        splitLine[10] + ',' +
        splitLine[9] + ',' +
        splitLine[11] + ',' +
        splitLine[7] + ',' +
        splitLine[32] + '\n';
    return line; 

}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    string inPath = argv[1];
    string outPath = argv[2];
    
    std::ifstream inFile;
    std::ofstream outFile;

    inFile.open(inPath.c_str());
    outFile.open(outPath.c_str());

    string line;
    while(std::getline(inFile,line))
    {
        vector<string> split = splitStr(line, ';');
        if(split[3][0] == 'E' || split[3][0] == 'T')
        {
            outFile << makeCSVLine(split);
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
}
```

Both running on redhat 8.
I'm sure that its some mistake I'm making in terms of c++ efficiency (possibly somewhere in how im utilizing strings and vectors and whether they need to be re-sized repeatedly per loop)but I'm not sure what it could be. If anyone could help shed some light that would be great.

Comment: If you think your code is inefficient, maybe you could post it on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Since PHP is obviously interpreted, and C++ not, what are the C++ compile options ... debug build, release build, optimizations, etc.?

Comment: I included the compile options but here they are again in case they were easy to miss g++ parse.cpp -o parse -O2 -std=c++1y

Answer (score 0):

I/O is often a huge bottleneck in C++, with a fairly large overhead per function call. I've seen instances of unoptimized C++ I/O being slower than python I/O. While the rest of your code isn't heavily optimized (e.g. adding characters one at a time to buf is probably somewhat slower than using .substr()), it doesn't look terrible.

To speed stuff up, try reading and writing the file in one go each. That is, create a char* buffer the size of the input file and use one call of ifstream::read, then parse the buffer. When writing, write to a char* buffer, and at the end, write that buffer to a file with one call of ofstream::write.

Comment: Thanks for this, use c style io operations defiantly lowered the execution time, seems as though i'm also bottlenecked by my use of the splitStr function...